# Tmux changing the Quiting Message Color

Tags: tmux, macos

When I use tmux, I use x to kill a window and then the message shows up. However, the color of the message is black, which is similar to my background and makes it hard for me to distinguish. Does anyone know how to change that? Thank you!

[image: Message and Background]

System: Macos Shell: zsh Background: OceanicNext Minimal `.tmux.conf`:

```bsh
set -g status
set -g status-fg white
TERM=screen-256color
set-option -g default-terminal $TERM
set -g mouse on
set -g status-position bottom
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right '#{prefix_highlight} #{weather} #(tmux-spotify-info)#[fg=colour8,bg=default] %m/%d #[fg=colour8,bg=default] %H:%M:%S '
set -g status-right-length 50
set -g status-left-length 20
setw -g window-status-current-style 'fg=colour15 bg=default bold'
setw -g window-status-style 'fg=colour87 bg=default'
set status-bg default
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change message-style to something more suitable to your status line or terminal background colour.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.